# How to show legends in kendo ui line chart multiple "X" Axis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI line chart for show multiple dates on "X" axis.
But the problem is Legends doesn't show.
I have tried too much but not success.
I put here an example, please help me to show legends.

http://dojo.telerik.com/uFemi/7

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the name property of the series:

```
   series: [{
      name: "value1",
      field: "value1",
      categoryField: "date1",
      categoryAxis: "cat1",
      tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                template: "#=kendo.format(\'{0:d}\', dataItem.date1)#: #= value #"
            }, 
    }, {
      name: "value2",
      field: "value2",
      categoryField: "date2",
      categoryAxis: "cat2",
      tooltip: {
                visible: true,
                template: " #= kendo.format(\'{0:d}\', dataItem.date2) #: #= value #"
            },          
    }],
```